# Python statsmodels: memory error

Tags: python, memory

I'm trying to do vector autoregression. The time series has 526 examples (days) with 972196 columns (each entry in the matrix is a single float value).

I'm running into memory errors using Python's `VAR` module:

```
user:~/path/autoregression$ python Mar12_autoregression.py
/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/pandas.py:56: FutureWarning: The pandas.core.datetools module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use the pandas.tseries module instead.
  from pandas.core import datetools
/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py:461: FutureWarning: `rcond` parameter will change to the default of machine precision times ``max(M, N)`` where M and N are the input matrix dimensions.
To use the future default and silence this warning we advise to pass `rcond=None`, to keep using the old, explicitly pass `rcond=-1`. 
  params = np.linalg.lstsq(z, y_sample)[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mar12_autoregression.py", line 124, in <module>
    var_autoregression(adj_orig, num_nodes)
  File "Mar12_autoregression.py", line 95, in var_autoregression
    lag_7_results = model.fit(7)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 438, in fit
    return self._estimate_var(lags, trend=trend)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 461, in _estimate_var
    params = np.linalg.lstsq(z, y_sample)[0]
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2004, in lstsq
    bstar = zeros((ldb, n_rhs), t)
MemoryError
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR, DynamicVAR

def var_autoregression(adj_orig, num_nodes, seq_length=7):
    #adj_orig is a dict object with int keys and sparse_csr_matrix values, 
    #unless there is an int key with an empty list value.

    intermediate_build = []
    for i in range(len(adj_orig.keys())):
            #Build a 526x(986*986) matrix and convert to a pandas dataframe. Remove NAs.
            curr = adj_orig[adj_orig.keys()[i]]
            if isinstance(curr, list):
                    makevec = 100*np.ones((num_nodes*num_nodes)) #986*986 
            else:   
                    makevec = curr.toarray().flatten() #986*986
            intermediate_build.append(makevec)

    #Convert the list with 526 elements, each with size 986*986, to a pandas dataframe with 526 rows and 986*986 columns.

    i_build = np.asarray(intermediate_build)
    #print i_build.shape, 'here' #(526, 986*986) as it should be.

    col_list = [str(i) for i in range(num_nodes*num_nodes)]
    pd1 = pd.DataFrame(i_build, columns=col_list)

    #Need to insert dates into the first column
    pd1.index = pd.date_range("2016-01-01", "2017-06-09")
    pd2 = pd1[pd1['0'] != 100]

    model = VAR(pd2)

    lag_7_results = model.fit(7)
    print lay_7_results.summary()

    return 0
```

Any suggestions on how I can do vector autoregression on big data?

**EDIT (responding to a comment):**

Each row of 972196 is a flattened adjacency matrix. This is not images; it's graphs. I'm tracking how the adjacency matrix evolves over time.

Small example: say there are 3 people in the graph, and they exchange messages over 526 days. For each day, if there is communication between person i and person j, I record a '1' in the adjacency matrix in row i, column j.

If on the first day, person 0 sends a message to person 1, and person 2 sends a message to person 1, and there are no other messages sent, then the adjacency matrix looks like this:

```
0 1 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
```

If on the second day, person 1 sends a message to person 0 and person 1 sends a message to person 2 and there are no other messages sent, then the adjacency matrix looks like this:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 0 0
```

And so on, for 526 days. What I'm doing is flattening each adjacency matrix to a vector to be able to feed it in to an autoregression routine. That is, day 1 would look like this:

```
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

and day 2 would look like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

I then preprocess these binary vectors in a particular way to make the values floats instead of integers. Suppose for the sake of argument that day 1 becomes:

```
0, 0.1111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1111, 0
```

and day 2 becomes:

```
0, 0, 0, 0.2222, 0, 0.2222, 0, 0, 0
```

I'm trying to use past instances of the adjacency matrix (flattened, preprocessed vectors) to predict the next instance.

Comment: Can you state a bit more info on the data? Is a (1x1x526) a single timeline event? Are you tracking the time series for each pixel of a series of images?

Comment: @Joe please see the edit.

Comment: Since I don't fully understand, I will continue asking questions. :) But it might be possible to reduce the data. What do the corners of your matrices represent? e.g. every second element in `0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0`. And you could get rid of the center element, right? I guess your data contains redundancies, right? Communcation (i,j) is equal to (j,i) .