# Why am I getting a memory error with the python statsmodels?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, statsmodels

Hi I'm getting a memory error running a Tweedie GLM with statsmodels.  I've looked at [Python statsmodels: memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247651/python-statsmodels-memory-error) but there is not an answer on that post.

The computer I'm running this on has 64gigs of RAM and eight processors.  The shape of the data is `(722214, 47)`.

The below is my code:

```
formula = 'pp_log ~ C(atfault_model) + C(channel_model) + C(CLded_model) + C(credit_model_52778) + \
        C(credit_model_c6) + C(package_model) + C(ds_fp_paid_in_full) + C(ds_pn_prior_insurance) + \
        C(ds_ip_advanced_purchase) + C(credit_model_c5) + C(ds_ad_affinity) + C(ds_ak_alliance) + \
        C(ds_ly_loyalty_discount) + C(ds_mo_multipolicy) + C(ds_pf_performance) + C(majorvio_model) + \
        C(driver_age_model):C(marital_status_model) + C(minorvio_model) + C(multi_unit_model) + \
        C(unit_drv_exp_model) +  C(Vintiles) + C(safety_course_model) + C(instructor_course_model) + \
        C(RATING_CLASS_CODE_MODEL) + C(class_model):C(v_age_model) + C(class_model):C(cc_model)'

y, x = patsy.dmatrices(formula, train, return_type = 'dataframe')

weights = train['coll_eu']

lost_cost_model = smf.GLM(y, x-1, family = sm.families.Tweedie(link = sm.families.links.log, var_power = 1.5), weights = weights)

lost_cost_results = lost_cost_model.fit()
```

Additional Information:

The memory error is thrown at the following line:

```
lost_cost_results = lost_cost_model.fit()
```

The below is the traceback:

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 lost_cost_results = lost_cost_model.fit()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py
>   in fit(self, start_params, maxiter, method, tol, scale, cov_type,
>   cov_kwds, use_t, full_output, disp, max_start_irls, **kwargs)    1010 
>   return self._fit_irls(start_params=start_params, maxiter=maxiter,
>   1011                                   tol=tol, scale=scale,
>   cov_type=cov_type,
>   -> 1012                                   cov_kwds=cov_kwds, use_t=use_t, **kwargs)    1013         else:    1014
>   self._optim_hessian = kwargs.get('optim_hessian')
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py
>   in _fit_irls(self, start_params, maxiter, tol, scale, cov_type,
>   cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)    1131                     wlsendog,
>   1132                     wlsexog,
>   -> 1133                     self.weights).fit(method=wls_method)    1134             lin_pred = np.dot(self.exog, wls_results.params)
>   1135             lin_pred += self._offset_exposure
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression_tools.py
>   in **init**(self, endog, exog, weights)
>        47             self.wexog = w_half * exog
>        48         else:
>   ---> 49             self.wexog = w_half[:, None] * exog
>        50 
>        51     def fit(self, method='pinv'):
>
> MemoryError:

Add 2:

In the insurance industry, it's standard practice to bring everything in as a categorical variable.  Then once decisons are made to on how to smooth out each relativity, change what needs to be changed over to an numerical type and fit a polynomial or spline or whatever....

Once I used what variables I could as numerical, it ran fine...in only 3 minutes.  Case closed.

Comment: Use `try except` & identify the statement which is causing the error first.